# Simple Injector WPF Integration

Tags: simple-injector

I implemented the recommended startup in my WPF project and ran into a few small problems that I have worked around but wanted to let you know, either to be corrected or give feedback.

In RunApplication after

```
 var app = new App();
```

I needed to add:

```
app.InitializeComponent();
```

for the resource dictionaries defined in app.xaml to be loaded.

Further, because I configured my container with the startup view which relies on these resources I was unable to call  container.Verify() (as it seems to try instantiate the views) until after these resources are loaded, so that the first lines of RunApplication are now:

```
var app = new App();
app.InitializeComponent();
container.Verify();

var mainWindow = container.GetInstance<MainWindow>();
...(more init stuff)
 app.Run(mainWindow);
```

With this my program starts and works as expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question - feedback should be posted in the Github project: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer because I ran into the same problem and noticed the user did indeed figure out the problem on Simple Injectors GitHub issue forum: [WPF Integration #493](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/493)

See comments in code below of changed code from Simple Injectors WPF integration guide.

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        var container = Bootstrap();

        // RunApplication method placed here for simplicity
        try
        {
            var app = new App();

            app.InitializeComponent(); // This is needed to utilize Application.Resources XAML in MainWindow

            container.Verify(); // Verify after ResourceDictionaries are loaded from Application.Resources XAML

            var mainWindow = container.GetInstance<MainWindow>();

            app.Run(mainWindow);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // TODO: Log exception
        }
    }

    private static Container Bootstrap()
    {
        // Create the container
        var container = new Container();

        // Register types

        // Register windows and view models:
        container.Register<MainWindow>();

        return container;
    }
}
```